# Mark Selected Datatable Row based on Column Values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to mark several rows as SELECTED in a Datatable based on 2 column values each row has (The row has 3 columns but only the first 2 are the ones that I need to compare).

It currently works like this:

1. The Datatable is populated with several cities (Nothing marked as Selected yet). This are all cities from another source where users can select or deselect cities. But they see the total cities.
2. I then send an AJAX call with the user id to retrieve the actual selected cities so far.
3. When I receive the cities already selected, I want to be able to search the datatable by the first 2 columns, which are city and state. If column 1 and 2 match the information that was retrieved on step 2, the mark it as selected (Visually mark the row as a selected row).

Any idea is appreciated. Currently what I have been doing is the following:

```
function(data){  

    var maxOptions = serviceAreas.columns(0).data().eq(0).length;
    data.forEach(function(item) {

        for (var totalOptions = 0; totalOptions < maxOptions; totalOptions++) {

            checkedOption = serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).data()[0] + ',' + serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).data()[1];

            if (item == checkedOption) {
                serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).select();
                break;
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

So after this works but it takes too long since it has to parse the whole table for each matched location. I am trying to avoid the whole parsing the whole table and simply do something like:

If item is found in the datatable, mark it as selectable go for the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "keymap" over the options. By that you can skip the (slow) outer `forEach` loop completely. Also you only need to call the expensive `table().row().data()` chain once per row.

```js
var maxOptions = serviceAreas.columns(0).data().eq(0).length,
    checkedOption, rowData,
    options = [];

//create a lookup table
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    options[data[i]] = true
}
for (var totalOptions = 0; totalOptions < maxOptions; totalOptions++) {
    //only read data once per row
    rowData = serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).data()
    checkedOption = rowData[0] + ',' + rowData[1];
    //select() if checkedOption exists as key in options
    if (options[checkedOption]) serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).select();
}
```

Completely untested of course, cannot replicate your scenario easily, but this should certainly work a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you David. A couple of questions, on the last line with options[option], what is the "option" and the other is where is the checkedOption being compared in this case. Got a bit confused here but I see where you are going with this.

Comment: Hi David, I accepted your answer since I put my answer based on your scenario. Excellent work my friend.

Comment: Hey @LuisAlvarado, `option` was meant to be `checkedOption` :( sry for that.  Is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the idea of David (Thank you David), the code went from the previous one to:

```
function(data){ 
    var maxOptions = serviceAreas.columns(0).data().eq(0).length;

    for (var totalOptions = 0; totalOptions < maxOptions; totalOptions++) {
        rowData = serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).data()
        checkedOption = rowData[0] + ',' + rowData[1];

        if (data.indexOf(checkedOption) > 0) { 
            serviceAreas.row(totalOptions).select();
        }
    }
}
```

Not only does it transverse everything about 10x faster than before, but it simpler. The issue was that I was searching through the whole table for each individual state,city option found. In this case, I only do a one to one relation for each state,city found.

Comment: Yes, also faster than the original - but using an array with `data` as keys is even faster (as `options[checkedOption]` above), `Array.indexOf` is iterating each time, so it is slower.

Comment: @davidkonrad - When I grow up I want to be like you ^^. Yes, I applied your code and it went even faster. Amazing.